# Why is 80 added to nonce and length fields?

Tags: transactions

I'm currently reading "Signing ethereum transactions the hard way" (https://lsongnotes.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/signing-an-ethereum-transaction-the-hard-way/), and I am confused why 80 is added to nonce and the different length fields.

The author of the article states the following:

> The first field is the nonce, which is essentially the account’s count
> of transactions. As this is a new account, it is zero. which, in RLP
> format (see Ethereum yellow paper, to put it simple, it’s a variant of
> the classic “length+payload” structure), is 80

I opened up the Yellow Paper, but this is way too much math for me to even understand what goes on here.

Can someone explain me in plain English:

- Why is 80 added? Why can't I just specify nonce 0 instead of nonce 80 for the first transaction? (same question for the length fields)
- Why 80? Why not 70 or 90? Any reason for this particular value?

Comment: Without really knowing my guess is that the first digit denotes the length of the data (8 bits probably?) and the number after it is the real value. It could be zero-padded to be 800000000.

Comment: The [RLP](https://eth.wiki/en/fundamentals/rlp) encoding was defined that way. It deals mostly with byte arrays and list of items.

All integers except zero can be considered a bytes sequence so they are encoded as an array of bytes. The exception being the zero, which is encoded as an empty list.